# SP2013 Workflow for Blog site approval

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I need to create a workflow in SP2013, where I have a list of approvers and SharePoint should iterate through this list and pick one approver at one time when a blog is created and assign him the task. for the next iteration, the next approver from the list should be picked up and assigned the task. Is there a way I can have any flag in workflow - SPDesigner to do this? and also keep a track of last blog creation and approver assignee?

Thanks
AP

Answer (score 0):

You can create an approval workflow in SharePoint Designer.

1. Open the Microsoft SharePoint Designer.
2. Click on File tab and Open your SharePoint site.
3. Click on Workflows
4. Click on List Workflow and Select the blog library where you want the workflow to be associated
5. Next you can add "Action" -> "Start Approval Process"
6. Select the approver details
7. Save and publish

[A Sample SharePoint 2013 Approval Workflow Which can be Recalled by the Initiator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2012/08/16/a-sample-approval-workflow-which-can-be-recalled-by-initiator.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct you want to have a have Approver A for Blog Post 1 and Approver B for Blog Post 2 and then again Approver A for Blog Post 3 and so on and so forth.

The only way I can think of is to make use of a helper list. 
You could have a list like this:

```
List of Approvers

ID | Order | Approver | Last Active
-----------------------------------
3  | 1     | User1    | true
7  | 2     | User2    | false
19 | 3     | User3    | false
```

and a workflow that follows this schema:

1. Calculate: Get **Order** from **List of Approvers** where **Last Active** is true and add 1 to it, output to variable **calc**
2. Set variable **user** to **Approver** where **Order** is **calc**
3. If **user** is empty then set variable **calc** to 1 and set **user** to **Approver** where **Order** is **1**
4. Update **List of Approvers**, set **Last Active** to false where **Last Active**
   is true
5. Update **List of Approvers**, set **Last Active** to true where **Order** is **calc**

Answer (score -1):

You can create multilevel approval workflow using SharePoint designer. 
Create the workflow in Designer with SharePoint 2010 platform. 
Create the action as Start approval process to have the serial workflow with one approvar at one level.

When a user add a new item in the list, the 1st approval get the email notification and admin can take the action (approve or reject)

If the 1st approval approve the item, then it goes to the 2nd approvar.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/21ebdd31-ca2a-41c5-aadc-abbd63ac8bed/multiple-level-approval-workflow-for-sharepoint-online?forum=sharepointcustomization